# add mask to string in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

There is a crystal report in my project that will be showing confidential information like Credit Card No. Currently there is no masking for the credit card no. and I would like to mask the credit card no., for instance, '**XXXX XXXX 1234 5678**'. How can i do this in the crystal report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your credit card numbers are known to be 16 digits (most, but not all cards are 16 digit) and are numeric, you can do this

```
local numbervar cardno := totext({table.cardno},0,''); //cardno to string
"XXXX XXXX " + cardno[9 to 12] + " " + cardno[13 to 16]
```

If the card number is already a string, just omit the first line. You also may want to mask all but the last 4 digits, since the 8th to 15th digits represent the entire account number (See: [What your credit card numbers mean](http://computersolving.com/computer-tips-tricks/what-your-credit-card-numbers-mean/))

Comment: AmEx is 15 digits grouped 4,6,5.

Unless you have this data encrypted, I would venture to guess you are violating PCI standards.

Comment: If cardno i a string, it shoulbe declared as `local stringvar cardno` otherwise you get an error